# Meteor Factory, enzyme jest TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined randomly

Tags: reactjs, meteor, enzyme

I am getting below error randomly while testing my component using enzyme/jest

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
   at makeRelation (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:45:14)
   at packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:71:20
   at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:147:22)
  at walk (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:67:7)
   at packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:84:16
   at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:147:22)
   at walk (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:67:7)
   at Function.Factory._build (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:97:3)
   at Function.Factory.create (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:121:23)
   at makeRelation (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:45:22)
   at packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:71:20
   at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:147:22)
   at walk (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:67:7)
   at Function.Factory._build (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:97:3)
   at Function.Factory.create (packages/dburles:factory/factory.js:121:23)
```

My factory.defile is like:

```
Factory.define('users', Meteor.users, {
  createdAt: new Date(),
  username: faker.name,
  displayName: faker.name,
});


// And I am creating document like 
Factory.create('users', { role: 'guest' });
```

Comment: how does your error stack relate to the source you show? the line numbers in the stack are not from this it seem.

Comment: Isn't the issue that you are trying to overwrite the `role` field, but `role` is not defined in the `users` schema?

Comment: @ChristianFritz , that line relates to the mount statement in my test case.
Not seems to be an override issue.